# Image Tag lost in Image List

Tags: c#

I don't know if this is a well known bug, but the Tag property of an Image in a ImageList does not work properly.

```
Image thumbnail = Properties.Resources.jpgBaseThumbnail;
thumbnail.Tag = "BaseIcon";
```

If now I get the tag:

```
string imageTag = thumbnail.Tag.ToString();
```

I get it, no problem. But, If I do:

```
imageList.Images.Add(myKey, thumbnail);
string imageTag = imageList.Images[myKey].Tag.ToString()
```

I get an System.NullReferenceException (System.Drawing.Image.Tag.get returned null).

Even if I set the tag AFTER adding image to ImageList:

```
imageList.Images.Add(myKey, thumbnail);    
imageList.Images[myKey].Tag = "BaseIcon";
string imageTag = imageList.Images[myKey].Tag.ToString()
```

I get the null reference, too.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 updated to last version.

An I doing something wrong? For now, I using a 'workaround' by creating a Dictionary for each ImageList, where I can save the 'Tag', but It's an awful solution.

Comment: have you defined `imageList`? if yes, can you add code here?

Comment: I thinks the images on an ImageList are copies not references to the original. But the 2nd way ought to work. But it doesn't. Looks like a bug to me..

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar It's de default class, no private implementation

Comment: @TaW The second option (assigning tag AFTER adding to the ImageList collection) does not work, either. It looks like as if, when recovering the image from the collection, it makes a image bitmap copy, but Tag is not copied, so thats why is null

Comment: I know I tested it myself. Assignging brings up no error but __the degugger shows that the Tag is not set__. A bug in my book.

Comment: Not a bug. The indexer (which calls the [GetBitmap](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/managed/system/winforms/ImageList.cs,692) method) returns new Bitmaps. The _original_ images are [cached](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/managed/system/winforms/ImageList.cs,75) internally. No deep cloning.

Comment: @dr.null Knowing this, that the original images are cached internally, is there any way to access that image and its tag?

Comment: @Kaikus I posted a direct answer. However and as alternative, consider encapsulating the image info in a class and create a dictionary `Dictionary<imgKeyString, ImgInfoClass>`. Then you can get an image by the key from the `ImageList` and its extended properties from the dict. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Not a bug. The indexer (which calls the [`GetBitmap`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/managed/system/winforms/ImageList.cs,692) method) returns new Bitmaps. The original images are [cached](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/managed/system/winforms/ImageList.cs,75) internally.

Further to that, I don't think that the `Image.Tag` property is a factor in this context to be preserved. And yes, you can get the original images through `Reflection`.

Assuming you have an `ImageList` and you fill it like so:

```cs
// Images...
var bmp = Properties.Resources.Image1;
bmp.Tag = "Image 1";
img16.Images.Add("image1", bmp);

bmp = Properties.Resources.Image2;
bmp.Tag = "Image 2";
img16.Images.Add("image2", bmp);

bmp = Properties.Resources.Image3;
bmp.Tag = "Image 3";
img16.Images.Add("image3", bmp);

// And maybe some icons...
img16.Images.Add("Icon1", Properties.Resources.Icon1);
img16.Images.Add("Icon2", Properties.Resources.Icon2);
```

<sup>**Important**
Do not set the `Tag` property **after** inserting an image into the `ImageCollection` like your third code block.</sup>

Let's create a couple of extension methods to access a private field named `originals` in the base class where the original images and icons are kept:

```cs
public static class ImageListExtensions
{
    public static object Original(this ImageList imgList, int index)
    {
        if (index < 0 || index > imgList.Images.Count - 1)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();

        var flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
        var originalsField = imgList.GetType().GetField("originals", flags);
        var originalsValue = originalsField?.GetValue(imgList) as IList;
        var imageField = originalsValue?[index].GetType().GetField("image", flags);
            
        return imageField?.GetValue(originalsValue[index]);
    }

    public static IList<object> Originals(this ImageList imgList)
    {
        var lst = new List<object>();
        var flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
        var originalsField = imgList.GetType().GetField("originals", flags);

        if (originalsField?.GetValue(imgList) is IList originalsValue)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < originalsValue.Count; i++)
            {
                var val = originalsValue[i];

                lst.Add(val
                    .GetType()
                    .GetField("image", flags)
                    .GetValue(val));
            }
        }

        return lst;
    }
}
```

Now you can get an original image through the `Original` method and check its `.Tag` property:

```cs
if (img16.Original(0) is Image img) Console.WriteLine(img.Tag);
```

Or get them all if you want to by calling the `Originals` extension method:

```cs
foreach (var obj in img16.Originals())
{
    if (obj is Image img) Console.WriteLine(img.Tag);
    else Console.WriteLine(obj.GetType().Name); // Icon...
}
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much! I need the 'Tag' property to flag if the image contains a real thumbnail o a default icon. I use the ImageList for a ListView with image thumbnails (all the images in a folder). Building the thumbnails is expensive (specially the thumbnails of PDF files), so I, first, populate the ImageList with base icons (set image.Tag="baseIcon"), and create a background worker to build the thumbnails, update the image in the ImageList, and change the Tag (set image.Tag = 'Thumbnail")

Comment: Sorry, but there is something in the code that does not work properly for me. originalsField gets the FieldInfo, but originalsField?.GetValue(imgList) returns null ... :( I have tried a variation of this code to recover a string field, and there is no problem. Maybe need some changes for ILists?

Comment: For your info, the code works flawlessly to recover other tipe of fields in an ImageList, as imageSize (Size), or imageCollection (ImageCollection) (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ImageList.cs)

Comment: @Kaikus You're welcome. Yes you can use the same logic to access whatever you need from the base class. As for `.GetValue` returns null, make sure that you don't do something like `imageList.Images[myKey].Tag = "BaseIcon";`. Otherwise the `originals` field will no longer be a useful field for you. Now you know how to get the original objects and other info from the base class. Enjoy trying.

Comment: That was! I was assigning the tag property to the image inside the collection in another section of my code, and thus, invalidating 'originals'. Removed it and now it works! :)

Comment: Uff... Theese 'originals' are quite volatile! Later on, in my code, I assign the imageList to another ListView (myListView.LargeImageList = imageList). Just by doing this, 'originals' is wipped out!. Don't know if, in the end, it's worth continuing trying to use that unstable 'Tag' property. In any case, I am infinitely grateful for your help! ;)

Comment: @Kaikus Most welcome Mr. Kaikus. I wanted from you to try it yourself to reach that conclusion and consider the alternative approach that I suggested in my last comment in your question. In addition, `Refelection` is slow.